# Laravel roles and permissions

Tags: laravel

I am new with Laravel and i am trying to build an application based on roles, but in my case the user can have only one role (there is no a pivot table between users and roles) and we can create new role us we like(assign many permissions to one role). Any help? and thanks a lot

Comment: err, what you have tried..? also, any reason against using packages? if you don't mind, you can learn from existing packages...

Answer (score 0):

So here is one way I would do it.

You need 2 tables :

- One table I would call "ranks", inside it you can have everything about the rank itself :
  Its id of course, but also :
  Is it an admin rank ? (all permissions)
  What's it name ? ...
- One table I would call "ranks_abilities", inside it you can have everything about what a rank can do
  Therefore, it would have three columns : an id, a rank_id, and the name of the ability

And you need to put the rank_id inside the users table.

Note : if you wanna do it really nicely, you can have a table "abilities" containing all the possible abilities, and you'd reference their ids instead of the name

So how would it work ?

You would therefore have three models :

- User
- Rank
- RanksAbility

Inside of your User model, you'd have a belongs_to relationship to the Rank model (call it rank)
Inside of the Rank model, you'd have a has_many relationship to the RanksAbility model (call it ranks_abilities)

I guess we are now fine with the database structure, let's get to the point of allowing to do something.

So, of course, where a login is required, you have the auth middleware that does it perfectly

Then, to handle the permissions itself, there are several ways to do it, here is one I would recommend.

Step 1 :

Create a policy for some action for example if you have posts you can create a PostPolicy (https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authorization#creating-policies)

If, you want, for example, a permission so that a user can edit all posts, you'd have an update method in that PostPolicy

```
public function update(User $user, Post $post)
{
    return $user->hasPermission('post.update'); // You can also add other permissions for example if the post belongs to your user I'd add || $post->user_id == $user->id
}
```

I would do something like that.

Then, you'd have to make the hasPermission method.

So, in your User model, you could put something like this :

```
public function hasPermission($permission){
    if(!$this->relationLoaded('rank')){
        $this->load('rank', 'rank.ranks_abilities');
    }
    if(!$this->rank){
        return false;// If the user has no rank, return false
    }
    foreach($this->rank->rank_abilities as $ability){
        if($permission === $ability->name){
            return true;// If the user has the permission
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

And here the method is done.

Last step, you can use all the methods listed here https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authorization#authorizing-actions-using-policies to avoid an user from doing something he can't.

Personally, I would do a FormRequest, and handle the authorization with it (https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#authorizing-form-requests).

I hope to be clear, if you have any more questions go ahead

Answer (score 0):

For setting up customized user roles and permissions, you may give a try to https://thewebtier.com/laravel/understanding-roles-permissions-laravel/.

It's a complete guide on how to setup roles and permissions in your Laravel project.